# how to access a json in a json in a array with ngfor

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I use Angular 6 and Firebase. I would like to display the list of all appointments. Here is how I proceed.

service.ts

```
getRDV() {
  this.rdvList = this.firebase.list('/rdv');
  return this.rdvList;
}
```

Model:

```
export class RDV {
  key: string;
  date: string;
  heure: string;
  spe: string;
  uidpat: string;
  uid: string;
  status: string;
}
```

In ts :

```
export class ListComponent implements OnInit {

  rdvList: RDV[];

  constructor(
    private usersService: UsersService,
    private router: Router
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    var x = this.usersService.getRDV();
    x.snapshotChanges().subscribe(item => {
      this.rdvList = [];
      item.forEach(element => {
        var y = element.payload.toJSON();
        y["$key"] = element.key;
        this.rdvList.push(y as RDV);
      })
      console.log(this.rdvList)
    })
  }

}
```

In Html :

```
<tr *ngFor="let rdv of rdvList| myfilter:term, let i = index">
  <div *ngFor="let item of rdvList.rdv.key">
    <td> {{item.$key}} </td>
    <td> {{item.uidpat}} </td>
    <td> {{item.date}} </td>
    <td> {{item.heure}} </td>
    <td> {{item.spe}} </td>
    <td> {{item.uid}} </td>
    <td> 
      <button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="onViewUser(user?.uid)">
        Choisir
      </button> 
    </td>
  </div>
</tr>
```

DATA STRUCTURE:
[image]

I really can not fix the problem should I change how to give them are pushed in the table or use the template `*ngfor` to adjust the problem.

[my JSON console.log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uiNCx.png)

Comment: please paste your json here

Comment: what is snapshotchanges(_) in ngOnit, why dont ou directly subscribing result from x. eg. this.getBenef() is returning a value from service just like getRDV()
      this.getBenef().subscribe(
        res => {
            this.benefaccountList = res['list'];
.............................

Comment: please post your json response here

Comment: The error makes sense. You're expecting a list of appointments. But you're fetching from `/rdv`. This will have dates at the top level and within each date, there will be appointment objects. I personally feel, since each appointment object already has a date field in it, you don't need to add each appointment to the hierarchy. Later you can filter it using the date itself.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently what you want here is just a list of Appointment Objects that are nested below the DATE keys.

If you want to extract all these appointment objects, you'll have to map them like so:

```
export class ListComponent implements OnInit {

  ...

  ngOnInit() {
    var x = this.usersService.getRDV();
    x.snapshotChanges().subscribe(item => {
      const appointments = [];
      item.forEach(element => {
        var y = element.payload.toJSON();
        y["$key"] = element.key;
        appointments.push(y);
      });

      // This is the operation
      this.rdvList = appointments
        .flatMap(item => Object.values(item))
        .filter(item => typeof item === "object");

      console.log(this.rdvList)
    })
  }

}
```

The first `flatMap` will extract all the values from each object in your array. This will contain your appointment objects as well as date string.

So you'll have to apply a `filter` to all the items mapped by the first `flatMap` operation to filter out only those items which are of type `Object`

This should give you your Appointment Objects in `rdvList` property which you can then loop through in your template using `*ngFor`